# How to compare the efficiency of two encoding schemes or hypothesis languages?

Tags: formal-languages, terminology, efficiency, coding-theory, encoding-scheme

My question is pretty basic, I'm looking for a named method if you know one, but also proper terminology, further reading, and anything this reminds you of if you don't. (I'm new to this, don't have the right terminology and just need a starting point so I can help myself.)

I'm trying to interpret the vector inputs to a black-box controller (which I can model as finite-state machine). I can see them and they look like a series of symbols but it is too variable (stochastic) to easily define an "alphabet" based on repetition and it isn't clear how the symbols are grouped. In other words it isn't clear whether they use something like block coding where each symbol is the same number of vectors in a sequence, or convolutional coding where symbols can have different numbers of vectors.

The controller operates a linear actuator (it just goes up and down) and the inputs are large vectors from a CNN. It's essentially a pong playing robot. I make predictions by modeling the controller as binary decision tree that maps each putative symbol to an exact position of the actuator. This is very similar to a language induction problem for a finite-state machine. Recall that a finite automaton can be a representation of a regular language. Also recall that finite automaton can characterized in terms of its memory requirements and computational complexity, hence a regular language can too.

1. I know that the controller is optimal. There is no controller which has both less memory and less computational complexity. If I have two guesses at coding schemes and each are able to predict actuator position equally well then I want to pick the coding scheme which implies the least complexity and memory. So how does one go about evaluating the resource requirements of a coding scheme (raw inputs-> symbols) and grammar (rules about symbols) in combination?
2. I need to keep in mind that I might be wrong that it digitizes its inputs into symbols at all. So what are the signs that it is not digital? (such as, if I divide the symbols into smaller symbols and it still works just as well, ad infinitum, that probably means the symbols are meaningless).

[image: Question explained pictorially]

---

If you don't think I've given enough information keep in mind that I don't expect a detailed answer (but I'm happy to offer more). An acceptable answer is something of the form "I think you need to look into ____.", "This sounds like ____ in which case we often use ____.", "This sounds like a paper I read, see ____.", or "The ____ metric compares the level of the difficulty of a task to the number of symbols in the language required to perform that task and tells you how efficient a language is at that task."

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  I'm a bit confused.  Can you give us a bit more context?  You mention an automata, a controller, and a coding scheme.  What are they?  What data do you have, and what are you trying to do with it?  What are you trying to accomplish, and what approaches have you considered, and why have you rejected them?  Are you given some input and trying to learn an automaton that will accept those input strings?  What research have you done?  Have you studied automata learning and grammar induction?  What does this have to do with coding schemes?  What do *you* mean by better?

Comment: @D.W. the question seems to be misunderstood a little. The data are spike trains and the controller is a neural network (as mentioned in the original edit) but I doubt its relevant to a cogent answer since context is what I seek in the first place. Grammar induction is a possible context, but I'm not interested in the rules applied to symbols but uncovering the symbols themselves from a noisy channel. It may help me decide how to choose between two possible symbol sets, but the Wikipedia page does not discuss performance metrics. It's too high-level as I just need to compare existing sets.

Comment: @D.W. better="The correct guess should imply both the least storage and the least complexity on the part of the controller. " 
Current approach=I thought to myself: "If two encoding schemes produce the same prediction but one has fewer symbols then the one with fewer symbols seems better. Hmm, I'm out of my ken here I better talk to some CS folks."
How to make symbols: Do kmeans on spike rasters (from a RNN) to identify repeated patterns. These are symbols, now use decision trees to map symbols to the actuator position. Repeat in different ways and get same prediction quality, which is best?

Comment: OK.  Please edit the question to incorporate this information into the question, and to read well for someone who encounters it for the first time (don't just add "EDIT:", but revise your post).  Make sure to include all relevant context.  We want questions to be self-contained, so that people don't have to read the comments to understand your question, so all relevant information should be incorporated into your post.  What's a spike train?  Is it a sequence of numbers? Why do you say that a neural network is like an automaton? A neural network computes a continuous function and is stateless.

Comment: I don't understand what a coding scheme is.  What format would it take?  Can you give a precise mathematical definition?  How does a coding scheme influence the amount of storage and complexity?  Storage of what?  How does the coding scheme influence the neural network?  How does an encoding scheme produce a prediction?  What's an actuator position?  What is given to us, what are we supposed to produce, and what is fixed in advance?  It's hard to understand what's being asked without understanding what the words you're using refer to.

Comment: @D.W coding scheme: Coding schemes need 2 things, a way to separate symbols and a mapping from inputs to symbols (see wiki~Forward_error_correction). My inputs are vectors so I need to decide how many vectors constitute a symbol (block coding) or if they can have different numbers of vectors (convolutional coding). Once you have a separation scheme you need to identify symbols. Treat each putative symbol as a tensor and use a distance metric to group tensors by similarity, the centroid of the group is the symbol prototype. New inputs are identified as symbols according the closest prototype.

Comment: @D.W. "How does a coding scheme influence the amount of storage and complexity?" this is the heart of my question and something I would like to know. 

"It's hard to understand what's being asked without understanding what the words you're using refer to." ~ there are two kinds of questions, those that seek context and those that seek solutions. You appear to want to offer solutions. I only need context. What does this remind you of? What does it SOUND like I'm talking about (since I can't yet describe it better). Once I have acquired the terminology I can help myself.

Comment: @D.W. 
It's like I'm asking for a SciFi book recommendation, in which case all that is important is what other books I've liked. If you think you need more than what my latest edit provided then you're too nice and trying too hard. I just need some cursory recommendations, if you don't have any then it's probably just not the area of CS (channel coding) you are familiar with.

Comment: I also don't understand the question, here (though it's not related to anything I know much about). But, based on your five detailed sub-questions, it looks very broad to me.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It is broad. I'm reading up on language induction which may help me adapt the language but it has two parts that may or may not be distinct from each other: A) If you have two languages that do the same computation but one has more symbols in its alphabet than the other what conclusions can you draw about the storage requirements and complexity of the equivalent automata? B) How do you do language induction when you can see the inputs but can only guess what constitutes a string or a symbol? Am I on the track to clarifying my meaning yet?

Comment: Ahh.  Perhaps there is a bit of a culture here that we should explain.  This site's format works best for specific, narrowly scoped questions where you've already done some research and can articulate a specific question.  "I'm asking for a SciFi book recommendation, in which case all that is important is what other books I've liked" questions aren't really suitable here (see our [help/dont-ask]; recommendations for readings generally aren't suitable for our site format, as they're too subjective and don't have a right answer; questions that are too broad don't work well here).

Comment: Its a broad category but not a broad question. No doubt culture plays a role. The question is nonetheless difficult to articulate at the moment. Often when an expert in one field asks an expert in another field a question they have more trouble understanding one another than if the asker was a general novice. I'm working on a revision (with set notation and figures) Should I make a new question or just change this one?

Comment: @D.W. It should be very concrete now. I'm not asking for a book recommendation I'm asking for named methods, similar problems, or anything this reminds a person of. Of course if someone has a detailed answer I wouldn't turn it down (but I would I would ask them where they got their info).

Comment: I wonder though if it might be reduceable further to just: How to quantify the complexity of a finite-state-machine and how to quantify the "recognizability", "comparability", and "expressive power" of my L1 and L2 hypothesis languages? I would have to map my clustering algorithm to a finite-state-machine too. Should I try to make 2 separate questions and ask it like that?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was just tree depth. What I needed to do was learn about evaluating the complexity of finite automata and how we can use a decision-tree model ([decision-tree complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_model)) to put bounds on the complexity of an automata ([analysis of algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)). So I take my two coding schemes (call them A and B) and I make binary decision tree to predict the output of my system based on the inputs provided by the coding schemes. If both coding schemes A and B are equally useful for predicting the outputs but A requires a tree depth of 15 while B requires a tree depth of 54 then A is "better".  This is because our decision-tree model of the system is simpler when using A than when using B and as stated before we strongly believe that our system is as simple as possible.

Of course I also need to include the complexity of the coding scheme itself but that just goes with alphabet size since it is a Nearest Neighbor search.

So it was under my nose, I just needed some context.